# How do I configure Setup And Deployment Project to use transformed app config?

Tags: app-config, transform, setup-project, setup-deployment, slowcheetah

I've been using [SlowCheetah](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx)  to transform my app.config files and this part is all working fine. The correct transforms are applied to AppName.exe.config when I build the windows client application.

The problem I have is that the S&D Project always looks for app.config which obviously does not contain the updated values.

How can I configure the S&D project to look for AppName.exe.config and package that instead?

Comment: I think this is fixed with the more recent versions of SlowCheetah, can you try it out and let me know if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some lengthy research it seems this is not possible when building an MSI using VS 2010 Setup & Deployment. 
It may be possible to do with MSBUILD as this is more powerful and flexible but I currently don't have the time to explore that avenue in detail.

So for the time being as a temporary workaround I have entered the values in app.config for the production environment as this is what the MSI will use.
My transforms are still in place for other environments. But seeing as I don't deploy to other environments with MSI it doesn't really matter.

At some stage I will sort this all out with a build server and CI.

Hope this helps someone, someday.